# Knockout Template Binding events

Tags: knockout.js

Am working with knockout template binding, i just want to know is there any way to trigger an event after template happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the docs on the available hooks: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_3_using_afterrender_afteradd_and_beforeremove

`afterRender` works for any template, while `afterAdd` and `beforeRemove` only apply when using the `foreach` option.